# How to add custom model modifier like in most gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mixins

I want to DRY some model functionality like in a lot of gems.
For example in gem [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) we should just add `acts_as_taggable` to any model to enable tagging on it.
How I can add my own `include_god_mode` model modifier into my rails project?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Rather, you should provide a module that can be mixed into your models.

Comment: And I need to include this module into f.e. ActiveModel to been available in all models?

Comment: No, you'd include it in the models that actually want it. The point is that you shouldn't be polluting *every model* with such functionality.

Comment: But I don't want to write "include MyModule::feature".
I want to write like "acts_as_taggable" but "my_feature". How I can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that it is implemented by simple class extending and mixing.

For example in the `acts-as-taggable-on` gem there are a lot of modules which included into ActiveRecord::Base so `acts_as_taggable` in a model is just a syntax sugar.

Here is `acts-as-taggable-on` sources with including:

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable
  ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagger
end

if defined?(ActionView::Base)
  ActionView::Base.send :include, ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

So if I want to add such sugar to my model I need to include a method into ActiveRecord::Base (or similar superclass in case of ActiveRecord ORM) that will include module with my stuff.